# Model of a system of set theory

Tags: set-theory

I was trying to understand Easton's theorem's proof. But I am not able to understand a few terms- model of a system of set theory, ranked variables, free variables, abstraction term, set constant, ranked formulas, rank of a variable. Can anyone please explain these terms?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you are trying to read Easton's original paper.

Don't.

For one thing, it uses an archaic language of forcing, which have been revamped and clarified since then. You can find a modern account in books like Jech **Set Theory**, or Sy Friedman's book about class forcing.

Regardless, it seems that you might not be comfortable enough with the basics of set theory. We say that an ordered pair $(M,E)$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$ if $M$ is a set, and $E$ is a binary relation on $M$ such that the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ are true when we interpret $E$ as the membership relation of $M$.

Note that sometimes we don't take models of $\sf ZFC$, but just a "sufficiently large, finite fragment of $\sf ZFC$", which means we only take finitely many axioms, and not all the theory.

In either case, you might want to improve your grasp on the basics of set theory (up to and including forcing, which is not so basic anymore) and logic before you try to tackle Easton's theorem.